# FCM - Send to topics and "Not Registered" error

Tags: android, firebase, registration, firebase-cloud-messaging, subscribe

I developed an Android app that subscribes to a topic (`subscribeToTopic()` in `OnCreate` of main activity) and then receives notifications sent by my server to that topic.

The problem is that, from time to time, someone complains that notifications cease to arrive. In this case, I usually ask the user to use a function, included in my app, that reads the Firebase Registration Token and sends it to me via email (I don't usually use or store it).

Then, I try to send a notification to that Token and FCM Server answers with the `Not Registered` error! How can it be `Not Registered`? When using the Topic Subscription, shouldn't Firebase manage the whole "*token process*" and take care of its renewal?

Is there some way to inform the app that it is not registered anymore and take appropriate actions? Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/nnDDJItxtHQ

Comment: You mention that your app  "reads the Firebase Registration Token". Where are you reading the token from? Are you reading it from somewhere in your app where it is stored, or are you calling getToken()?

Also do you have any idea if the user uninstalled and reinstalled the app or if they updated the app, since these actions can invalidate an existing token.

Comment: Did you notice if this is happening on some specific devices?  also, did the user use the "force-stop" button in settings on your app in the past?

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled in the client side? By putting another `subscribeToTopic()` in the `onTokenRefresh()`?

Comment: Cumulative answers:  
- my app reads token from `getToken()` in `onTokenRefresh()` and stores it in Preferences;  
- no idea if user uninstalled/reinstalled/update app, but since `subscribeToTopic()` is called in `OnCreate`, it should not be relevant in most cases;  
- I don't have statistics about device model or android version but I'm going to create one;  
- `subscribeToTopic()` in the `onTokenRefresh()` sounds  the right idea: I'm going to try; maybe it will take days to understand if it worked

Comment: @mdicosimo Let us know if it works. Cheers!

Comment: BTW: subscribeToTopic() in onCreate() is ok. no need to put it inside onTokenRefresh(). I am more concern about device specific issues.

Comment: After adding `subscribeToTopic()` in the `onTokenRefresh()` it seems that the issue is mitigated since I receive fewer complaints. Nevertheless some user is still experiencing it and I have no idea how understand why.
It doesn't seem limited to some phone model or vendor: most cases were from Samsung phones but some were also from Asus and Sony.

Comment: The problem keeps being reported: from time to time some user complains about notifications not working; when I try to send a notification to the token of that user, the answer is "Not Registered". Why??? :-(

Comment: Again, another user reported the problem. He confirmed that app was installed but when I sent the notification the answer was "Not Registered"

Comment: @mdicosimo have you solved your problem or not? because i got same problems.

Comment: No pal, sorry. As time passes it is reported less frequently: I don't know if it is because I'm losing users or FCM is improving :-) Last reports were from Samsung phones.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are facing the same issue

Comment: No, I didn't. It seems that it is happening less frequently but I still have some complaints. The last ones were always from Samsung phones (recent models). Could you share your experience?

Comment: I also see this error reported by users from Samsung devices. Any luck in the years since this was posted?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly for your case, but see if it helps!
I was facing the same issue. Here is how I fixed it (iOS specific, android was working out of the box)-

1. Uninstall the app from your phone
2. Clear ALL the tokens stored in your database for this particular account(or however you have set it up in your backend. In my case, tokens are tied to the account)
3. In componentDidmount-

   async componentDidMount() {
       this.checkPermission();
       this.createNotificationListeners();
     }

4.

```
  async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
      this.getToken();
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
  }

  async requestPermission() {
    try {
      await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      // User has authorised
      this.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      // User has rejected permissions
      console.log('permission rejected');
    }
  }

  async getToken() {
    try {
      const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
      if (!enabled) {
        await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      }

      const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
      if (fcmToken) {
        console.log("got token");
        console.log('fcm token:', fcmToken); //-->use this token from the console to send a post request via postman
        this.setState({ fcmToken });
        return fcmToken;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn('notification token error', error);
    }
  }
```

5.

```
 async createNotificationListeners() {
    /*
    * Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
    * */
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
        const { title, body } = notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    /*
    * If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
    * */
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    /*
    * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
    * */
    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
        const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
        this.showAlert(title, body);
    }
    /*
    * Triggered for data only payload in foreground
    * */
    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
      //process data message
      console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
  }
```

6. Finally, use the token that you see in the console as a value for the "to" key in your post request. You should no longer see the "notRegistered" error and should be getting push notifications.
   Done!!

Citations-https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about Android. I don't have any experience with iOS. Anyway your suggestion is quite difficult to put in practice with some user that I don't know personally and could live KMs far from me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When a user uninstalls/reinstalls the app old token is not working, you need to use the new token on behalf of the old token, use this override method on your FirebaseMessagingService extended class.

```
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
    Log.e("newtknn",token);
    super.onNewToken(token);
}
```

now you can you this token on your FCM service to send notifications. Thank You